# URL Rewriting: regular expression with strings

Tags: regex, .htaccess

I have a problem rewriting strings in the .htaccess file.

For letters I successfully used

```
    RewriteRule page/([0-9]+)$ page.php?num=$1
```

I tried on the same model to use:

```
    RewriteRule page/([a-z]+)/$ page.php?word=$word
```

were word can be a string from any length. 
I am expecting for example **page/hello** to be rewritten in **page.php?word=hello**.
But this is not functional.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: `$1` refers to group number 1: the regex enclosed within `()`. So in both cases you should use `$1`. Say for example you got `user/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?$` then you can use `page.php?id=$1&name=$2`.

Comment: @HamZa you should set this out as an answer.

Comment: @Martin Arguably, it could be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563772/reference-mod-rewrite-url-rewriting-and-pretty-links-explained

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$1` refers to group number 1: the regex enclosed within `()`. So in both cases you should use `$1`.

To clear up the confusion, lets give another example. Say you got

```
user/([0-9]+)/([a-z]+)/?$
```

then you can use

```
page.php?id=$1&name=$2
```

`$1` refers to `([0-9]+)` and `$2` refers to `([a-z]+)`

Comment: Ok great, thanks, I hadn't realized that $1 was refering to the group number.